# Trying to upload more then 5 GB data in azure blob

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload more than 5 GB files in the azure blob in using blob.PutBlockAsync and blob.PutBlockListAsync in asp.net core but it gives me error blocks not contain more than 50000:

https://prnt.sc/10ntmn3

Could you please let me know how I can upload the large file on the azure blob in the asp.net core project?

Comment: Please read [ask] to find out what is expected of questions. Please provide errors as text of just the error message, not as links to other sites with screenshots of IDEs with lots of text showing where answerers must hunt down the error message themselves.

Comment: Maybe you could increase the block size. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/157

Comment: Hello @keuleJ 

 I am trying to Uploading more than 5 Gb in my project but it gives me error:

RESPONSE Status: 400 The block list may not contain more than 50,000 blocks.


I am using this method for upload the file in chunks blob.PutBlockAsync and blob.PutBlockListAsync in asp.net core